# What coordinates are used to transform these metrics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, kerr-metric

From reading different texts on kerr metric it seem that the kerr metric can be written in two different metrices [Kerr metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric)

[image]
and [Kerr metric](http://luth2.obspm.fr/~luthier/carter/trav/Carter68.pdf)
[image]

Does anyone know what coordinate change can be used to get the second metric from the first one?

Comment: Would be nice with equation numbers, I didn't manage to find the second equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boyer-Lindquist coordinates have been used for the first metric:

$$x = \sqrt{r^2 + \alpha^2}\sin\theta\cos\phi$$

$$y = \sqrt{r^2 + \alpha^2}\sin\theta\sin\phi$$

$$z = r\cos\theta$$

With

$$\alpha = \frac{J}{Mc}$$

$$\rho = \sqrt{r^2 + \alpha^2\cos^2\theta}$$

$$\Delta = r^2 + r_2^2r + \alpha^2$$

$$r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$$